# Difference between Action bar and just a custom layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

What is the point of action bars in android if you can just use a custom linear layout and use that? You can add more robust functionality, you can do much more than with the regular app bar, it's less hassle to use. I can only see the advantage when you tie your action bar to the activity, but most of the apps now have different action bars or no action bars at all for different screens.

Why would one choose one over another, or what even is the use case of action bars

Answer (score 2):

As written in the google documentation https://developer.android.com/training/appbar

"The app bar, also known as the action bar, is one of the most important design elements in your app's activities because it provides a visual structure and interactive elements that are familiar to users. [Pay attention to the point 'familiar to users'] Using the app bar makes your app consistent with other Android apps, allowing users to quickly understand how to operate your app and have a great experience. The key functions of the app bar are as follows:

1. A dedicated space for giving your app an identity and indicating the user's location in the app.
2. Access to important actions in a predictable way, such as search.
3. Support for navigation and view switching (with tabs or drop-down lists)."

To your question.

Yes, it is a valid point that custom action bars provide very robust and diverse functionality, but the point here lies in UI/UX part of the software development.

As you saw in the documentation

1. Familiarity to users
2. Consistency in design

Users are not comfortable with design changes as in general, because

1. Most of them do not even care about the design they just have to do what they have to do.
2. They have to again familiarize themselves to the new design so that they could remember it and navigate through the user interface faster.

So keeping software development aside for a while it becomes a bit difficult for the end-user.

Also, It might be that the default UI elements work better with the operating system [Cache, CPU, etc. ]

Answer (score 2):

This is related to our **design** , I think when **design** is sync with `Action bar` then it is **better** to use it but if we have flexible **design** we have to use custom **Toolbar**.

Some of **benefits** of an `Action bar` that cause **developers** select it at first :

**-Makes important actions accessible in a predictable way (such as Search).**

**-Supports consistent navigation and view switching within apps.(If you use navigation component is very simple to use Action bar)**

**-Reduces clutter by providing an action overflow for rarely used actions.**

**-Provides a dedicated space for giving your app an identity.**

And finaly Should you replace `ActionBar` with `ToolBar`? YES and NO. YES if you want the flexible header that comes with the `Toolbar`, NO if you don not need those flexible header. by flexibility, you can do things like **adding** background **image**, **animations**,...